# Private members in JavaScript object with getters and setters

Tags: javascript

I am testing an JS object

```
gl.test = function () {

    var $ = jQuery;
    var _private = null;

    var _setStr = function ( t ) {
        _private = t;
    }

    var _getStr = function() {
        return _private;
    }

    var obj = {
        init: function ( str ) {
            _setStr(str);
        },

        test: function() {
            console.log( _getStr() );
        },

        EOF: null
    };

    return obj;

}();
```

When executing the following:

```
var test1 = gl.test;
var test2 = gl.test;

test1.init('test1');
test2.init('test2');

test1.test();
test2.test();
```

the result comes back as `test2` `test2`

This being an object I would expect for the order of execution not to matter and would expect for `test1` and `test2` to be returned as per:

```
var test1 = gl.test;
test1.init('test1');
test1.test();

var test2 = gl.test;
test2.init('test2');
test2.test();
```

Am I doing something wrong here?

Comment: you aren't creating a new instance of `gl.test`.

Comment: I'm way too tired. All I have to say is DUH. I knew it was something VERY STUPID.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As noted in the comments, you're not instantiating a new instance of `gl.test`. You could change it to not be an IIFE and use the `new` keyword

```
var gl ={}
gl.test = function () {
    ....
}

var test1 = new gl.test();
var test2 = new gl.test();
```

Live example: http://jsfiddle.net/19f9504u/

Comment: strange, when implementing your fiddle I'm getting `object is not a function error`...

Answer (score 0):

because test1 and test2 is the same object

// remove the autocall function and do this to gl.test

```
var test1 = gl.test();
var test2 = gl.test();
```

But it does not that how clases work in javascript by the way